# Custom Helper Class not found in Prestashop module

Tags: class, module, overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I created a helper class in prestashop 1.6 module, in the override directory. I included the file in main module file but the class is not found in tpl files. I need it there to call one static method from smarty template.
Any ideas with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please post some code...

Comment: Did you verified that your override is loaded and try to delete cache/class_index.php to check it was taken in account by the system ?

Comment: Thanks for the replay. Yes, I did.The funny thing is that the override works fine on my local machine on a test site but not on the production site.

Comment: delete root/cache/class_index.php file in your production site.